# Android, get results from activity other then started

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to create my own camera activities( one to take a picture, second to show it).
The problem is that, I start "takePictureActivity" as first, so I'll get results this Activity. But I want to get results from "ShowPictureActivity". Could someone suggest me how to make it works?

[a busy cat http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/1783/imgqtd.png](http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/1783/imgqtd.png)

MainActivity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this , TakePictureActivity.class);
     startActivityForResult(intent,  TAKE_PICUTRE);
```

TakePictureActivity:

```
      Itent intent = new Intent(this , ShowPictureActivity.class);
      intent.putExtras(image_data);
      startActivity(intent);
```

ShowPictureActivity:

```
         Intent _result = new Intent();              
    _result.setData(image_data);
   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, _result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **TakePictureActivity**  (Only Pseudo code)

Use, `startActivityForResult(intent,  Result_OK);` instead of `startActivity(intent);` to start **ShowPictureActivity**.

Now, implement `onActivityResult()` in **TakePictureActivity** like,

```
onActivityResult()
{
 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
 { 
     // Back from ShowPictureActivity with Result 
     // Set Result for your MainActivity:
     setResult();
     finish();
  }
}
```

This will send result to `onActivityResult()` of **MainActivity**: